# Change picture on mouse hover

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How to set in `ASP.NET` for `ImageButton` to change picture on mouse hover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<asp:ImageButton onmouseover="changePic(this);" ...
```

JavaScript:

```
function changePic(obj)
{
    obj.src = "<picture path>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do this in the client side - that is, using javascript.

You can add a client side `onMouseOver="this.src = 'pathToOtherimage'"` attribute and a similar one for `onMouseOut` to revert back.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done from the server-side (in the C# code), but rather must be done on the client-side (in JavaScript).  Starting with that fact, there are [various](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+change+image+on+mouseover) [approaches](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+change+image+on+mouseover) to the subject.